# How to run python script in FreeBSD

Tags: python, freebsd

Hy I dont find answer for my problem, how to run python script on freebsd?
I use:

```
# python script.py
#python: Command not found.
```

How to? Thansk

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the python interpreter. Once you've done that, your script will run.

Comment: See for details: https://docs.python.org/2/using/unix.html

Comment: I have installed python. But not working

Comment: Make sure the binary is in your path. You may want to take this question over to Super User.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the first line of your script. It needs to start with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), `#!`.

And on FreeBSD it is customary to use [`env`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=env) to get the correct location of interpreters. So your first line should be;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

At the time of this writing, Python 2.7 is the default Python in FreeBSD. But this might change in the future. If your script depends on a specific major version, you can specify it as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```